# How can I implement the C puts function in RISC-V assembly?

Tags: assembly, riscv

I am trying to implement `puts` in assembly. I have written a `putchar` function to write a char to STDOUT, but I am struggling to use that to create a loop to print out a whole string by calling `putchar` in a loop

This is the code that I have so far. Eventually I need to implement `gets` as well, but I am focusing on getting `puts` working first. When I test `putchar`, it works and prints out a character located in register a0. Currently, running the code prints out some empty white squares which I think are unknown characters.

```
.globl main
.equ STDOUT, 1
.equ STDIN, 0
.equ __NR_READ, 63
.equ __NR_WRITE, 64

.text
main:
    #prolog
    addi sp, sp, -104
    sw ra, 100(sp)
    
    #testing
    #jal ra, getchar
    #jal ra, putchar
    
    # Load prompt and call puts
    la a1, prompt
    la a3, prompt_end
    jal ra,puts
     #epilogue
    lw ra, 100(sp)
    addi sp, sp, 104
        ret
getchar:
    # Read up to 1 character from the terminal (stdin)
    li a7, __NR_READ
    li a0, STDIN
    mv a1, sp
    addi a2, zero, 1
    ecall
    ret

putchar:
    # Write the just read character to the terminal 
    addi a2, a0, 0
    li a7, __NR_WRITE
    li a0, STDOUT
    mv a1, sp
    ecall
    ret

# puts function
puts:
    puts_loop:
        # load current char into a0
        lb a0,0(a1)
        # check for end of string
        beq a1,a3,puts_loop_end
        # print using putchar
        jal ra,putchar
        # add 1 to a1 to move to next char
        addi a1,a1,1
        j puts_loop
    puts_loop_end:
        ret

.data
prompt: .ascii "Enter a message: "
prompt_end:
```

Comment: You are using a custom calling convention.  Is this intended?  I mean, it's clever, but do you know the standard calling convention?  If not, probably best to learn and use that.

Comment: What simulator environment are you using?  The one I know that uses the `write` (64) system call writes characters from main memory.  You give it a pointer to what bytes to write in a1 and a length/count of # bytes to write from memory in a2.  If you want to output a single byte from a register, use system call 11, `PrintChar`.

Comment: If you have one function calling another function (`main` calls `puts` and `puts` calls `putchar`, the `ra` register is being repurposed for the second call (`puts` calling `putchar`), and thus the first call (`main` calling `putchar`) will not be able to return to its caller.  To make that work you have to save & restore the `ra` register within `puts`.

Comment: The simulator I am using is the web version of [QtRVSim](https://comparch.edu.cvut.cz/qtrvsim/app/) The reason I have just been using the 64 system call is because that is how it was done in the file I was provided as reference for this task. Same as the custom calling convention, this is how I was taught to create functions and call them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's their definition of system call 64 found at RVSim (though we can note that it is the same for RARS):

```
.equ __NR_write,       64
    // ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
```

So, to use that for `putchar`, you'll have to write the character in `a0` (character to put) to memory as in the equivalent of:

```
char mem = a0;           // store to memory
write(STDOUT, &mem, 1);  // write 1 byte from the location of "mem" variable
```

(Note that taking the address of a variable (by unary &) in C generally forces that variable to live in memory, so that it has an address that can be used by that operator.)

However, for `puts`, since the bytes are already in memory, it would be better to count how many bytes are in the `puts` request and the write them all with one write as in the equivalent of:

```
char *where = a0;         // capture string address
int len = strlen(where);
write(STDOUT, where, len);  // write len bytes from the location of string parameter
```

Also technically we should check `write`s return value for errors.

When one function calls another, and then that function calls another, there are two return addresses involved, but this processor does not automatically stack return addresses, so that has to be managed by functions that call other functions.

However, `ecalls` do not participate in that problem this since they use an alternate mechanism to capture return addresses and return to their caller (they use the `epc`, to capture return addresses, and this is part of the interrupt mechansism).  So, if you do my above by inlining the loop of a `strcpy`, you won't have to stack the return address, but if you call `strcpy`, you will have to concern with stacking the return address.

Of course, you can stick to the `puts` calling `putchar`, but you'll have to stack the return address, and for any decent sized string, that will involve lots of system calls which are generally much more expensive, so we prefer to minimize them.

Also note fyi, that this code will run on RARS, another popular simulator with a good debugger, though it wants `.eqv` instead of `.equ`.